# CoderByte SimpleSymbols challenge: pattern recognition in strings (using RegExp)

Tags: javascript, regex, string

The problem:

Have the function SimpleSymbols(str) take the str parameter being passed and determine if it is an acceptable sequence by either returning the string true or false. The str parameter will be composed of + and = symbols with several letters between them (ie. ++d+===+c++==a) and for the string to be true each letter must be surrounded by a + symbol. So the string to the left would be false. The string will not be empty and will have at least one letter.

My code:

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) { 

  var arr = str.match(/[\+][a-zA-Z][\+]/g);
  var total = str.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g);

  if(arr === null || total === null)
     return false;

  else if(arr.length >= 1 && arr.length === total.length)
     return true;

  else
     return false;
 }
```

All the test cases except for these three pass:

```
 -"+z+z+z+"
 -"2+a+a+"
 -"+z+z+==+a+"
```

What I've done: checked the other [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39356/coderbyte-simplesymbols-challenge-in-javascript) on this problem. Tried another solution using regex but it had issues with input like "b".

I think the problem has something to do with when the pattern is "+char+char+" since a lot of the other test cases are like "++char+==+char+=="

Comment: Use a lookahead. `/\+[a-zA-Z](?=\+)/`

Comment: Thank you very much! All test cases passed.